# C++ constructors and function call

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class complex_1
{
    int a,b;
public:
complex_1()
{
    cout<<"Cat"<<endl;
}
    void assign_1(int x,int y)
    {
        a=x; b=y;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
    }
    complex_1 add(complex_1 c)
    {
        complex_1 temp;
        temp.a=a+c.a;
        temp.b=b+c.b;

    return (temp);
    }

};
int main()
{
    complex_1 x1,x2,x3;
    x1.assign_1(3,4);
    x2.assign_1(5,6);
    x3=x1.add(x2);
    x3.show();
   return 0;
}
```

Lets just not focus on this big random lines of codes, and let me explain my

point first.

I am studying constructors, and when practicing them I found this.

so suppose I made a constructor in the above code-named complex_1

and in main when I make instance(object) I did this,

```
complex_1 x1,x2,x3;
```

pretty basic and I know what it will send to stdout

the lines in my constructor which is-"Cat", 3 times.

so my question is

when I write in main

```
int main()
{
    complex_1 x1,x2,x3;// this give three function calls for constructor
    x1.assign_1(3,4);
    x2.assign_1(5,6);
    x3=x1.add(x2);/// this will give one more function call for constructor
    x3.show();
   return 0;
}
```

TLDR: here I am getting four "Cat", I know why there are three function calls, and I also know why there is 4th call it is because of this line.

```
x3=x1.add(x2);
```

My question is, why assigning x3 makes constructor function to call 4th time.

Comment: Look *inside* your `add` member function. Do you see anything familiar?

Comment: It's not assigning that's calling the constructor a 4th time. It's this line: `complex_1 temp;` You might also want to try implementing a destructor, and logging when it's called for more insight.

Comment: Try this in a debugger (step-wise) if in doubt. (This might be the reason for down-vote - not debugged before asked.)

Comment: oh, come on man I am a beginner, idk how to debug :(

Comment: @kanishktanwar you should learn as quickly as possible, knowing how to use a debugger on C++ code is a very good way to learn C++ code.

Comment: Revisiting my asked question after 2 years, i feel so dumb. :D @Scheff just watched you answering a question. and i know, i have seen this name before :p

Comment: The dumb experiences are the one you remember best. This is also a kind of learning... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, why assigning `x3` makes constructor function to call 4th time.

Because you have the following line in `add`.

```
    complex_1 temp;
```

Comment: I don't get it. is it has something to do with the copy constructor?

Comment: @kanishktanwar, no. When the above line in `add` is executed, the default constructor is called.to construct `temp`.